# Guidelines for when to start a new Solution or when to just add a new Project to existing Solution

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio when does a new Project belong within the current Solution being worked upon and when should I move the Project into its own Solution? What are the pros and cons of larger Solutions versus smaller Solutions? What should I be considering in making this decision? Does our chosen project methodology have any bearing on approach? Is this just about personal preference?

For example, we're currently building a new product for our clients which consists of a Silverlight application, with an ASP.NET MVC reporting console, and ASP.NET MVC administration console which all tie back against an existing client data database and a new shared application database. Currently the Visual Studio Solution for the engagement consists of everything - the Silverlight project, the Reporting website project, the Admin website project and two WCF Service Applications for data access to each database. Should any/all of this be split up into its own individual Solution?

I hope I've articulated the question in a way that makes sense. I'm confused as to what what my thought process should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerations:

- Dependencies - If the projects are dependent on each other then having them in the same solution can help to ensure that changes are proliferated to the dependent projects.
- Performance - I have several solutions made up of many projects and admittedly it takes a long time for the entire solution to load and build.
- Convenience - Obviously having all projects in one solution is more convenient than navigating across multiple open projects.  At the same time, multiple projects can clutter the solution explorer.

Additional Thoughts:

- If you need to debug two projects in parallel, for example a client / server pair, then two solutions allows you to debug both in separate instances of Visual Studio.
- Consider that your projects may change independent of your solution. For example, changing the project name may mean having to update multiple solutions and references.

I don't however think it's just personal preference.  Depending on the content there could be some significant differences in the approach taken.

Any other considerations I missed?

Here is a [good resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) from MSDN discussing the recommended approach to structuring projects and solution.  Worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to split them when the solution encapsulates different areas of responsibility.  Example in a document management system is handled by one department but the security is controlled by another department.  Also the number of people working on a solution should be consistent for the size of a solution.   Having too many people working on a single solution can be difficult at best.  Finally I would say when you want to share functionality with other projects or solutions I would break that up into its own solution.